PromQL фильтр по дате в метке
Есть метрика, которая выглядит так:
{__name__="app_common_opts", instance="my-servise",
release_date="2024.04.03 12:27:35"} 1

Мне нужно вытащить все записи за последние сутки, то есть release_date > "2024.04.03 12:27:35" - 1 day. Обращаю внимание, что фильтрация именно по полю "release_date" а не по дате сбору этой метрики.
ChatGPT мне выдал такой вариант, но он не работает.
app_common_opts{release_date=~"2024-04-03.*"} and time() - timestamp(release_date) <= 1d

Prometheus не смог понять ни time, ни timestamp. Пробовал и другие варианты, но Prometheus не хочет парсить такие конструкции.
